# How to trucnate/round to hour a localized datetime column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, truncate

I want to truncate/round to hour a localized datetime column in pandas python. For example if I have 2017-10-15 15:03:25+02:00 I would like to obtain 2017-10-15 15:00:00+02:00. Notice that I want to keep the timezone information.
The first thing I've tried is:

```
DF['dtColumn'].dt.floor('H')
```

This aparently works truncating to hour and keeping timezone information, the problem comes when the dst day comes, for example on 2017-10-29. Given the following code:

```
dt1 = datetime.datetime(2017,10,29,0,1)
dt2 = datetime.datetime(2017,10,29,1,1)
df = pd.DataFrame([('whatever', dt1),('whatever',dt2)])
df[1] = df[1].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Madrid')
df[1].dt.floor('H')
```

It produces the given error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-90-8319339cf020>", line 5, in <module>
    df[1].dt.floor('H')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 210, in f
    return self._delegate_method(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\common.py", line 132, in _delegate_method
    result = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\base.py", line 101, in floor
    return self._round(freq, np.floor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\base.py", line 93, in _round
    self._shallow_copy(result, **attribs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\base.py", line 213, in _ensure_localized
    result = result.tz_localize(self.tz)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.py", line 1826, in tz_localize
    errors=errors)
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 4380, in pandas.tslib.tz_localize_to_utc (pandas\tslib.c:75768)
AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from Timestamp('2017-10-29 02:00:00'), try using the 'ambiguous' argument
```

The error suggests using the 'ambiguous' argument which in case of ambiguity there is a predefined decision to make. But in my dataframe I wouldn't say there is such an ambiguity since I have the timezone info and I still want it after the rounding. I would prefer to avoid ambiguity.

I have also find the solution:

```
df.loc[:, 1].values.astype('<M8[h]')
```

This generally works except with complex timezones. For instance Nepal's timezone (Asia/Katmandu) is GMT+5:45. Again what I want to do is to truncate the to the hour the datetimes **in the local timezone**, after trying the code above  I observed this converts it to utc and then it truncates, so when it gets back to the localized datetimes I do not have it grouped in exact hours but to each :45.

For the code:

```
dt1 = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 29, 0, 1)
dt2 = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 29, 1, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame([('whatever', dt1), ('whatever', dt2)])
df[1] = df[1].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Katmandu')
df[2] = df.loc[:, 1].values.astype('<M8[h]')
df[2].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Katmandu')
```

We get the following result:

```
0   2017-10-28 23:45:00+05:45
1   2017-10-29 00:45:00+05:45
Name: 2, dtype: datetime64[ns, Asia/Katmandu]
```

This proves that the answer to my problem is not convert the datetimes to 'utc' or timestamps, trucate them and convert them back to localized.

The native library from python *datetime* has a method replace, where one can replace minute and second information for 0s but I haven't found anything similar for a datetime column in pandas. I would like to find a diferent solution to iterate row by row, since my dataframe is quite big.
 Any ideas on how to truncate to hours a datetime column in pandas according to this constraints?

Answer (score 1):

> I observed this converts it to utc and then it truncates

For everyone's benefit, I was having the same problem when truncating the date to a specific format. The `astype` function converts the date to `UTC`, that's why if you try to truncate a date that was previously converted to another timezone, it doesn't work.

The most efficient solution, and one that also works fast, is to use the `to_period` function as follows:

```py
# Comverting string column to datetime with UTC by default
df['column_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'], infer_datetime_format=True, utc=True)
# Converting to an specific time zone
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].dt.tz_convert('Europ
e/Amsterdam')
# Removing time offset if needed
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].dt.tz_localize(None)
# Truncating the datetime
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
```

If yo want to use another period take a look at this url: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases